# Is it possible to set up an Oak property index and avoid reindexing?

Tags: indexing, aem, jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

Even if I add the `reindex=false` property on the index, it still triggers a reindexing upon creation.

Comment: For the index to answer your queries, it needs to reindex existing data. What's your use case?

Comment: @catholicon I know that the data that I will be searching has not been created yet. So I do not need to index existing data and the reindexing can be quite costly on a large repository

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is **No**

Reindex flag is primarily used for index updates. When a new index is created, it is index by the respective processor. For sync (mostly non lucene), the indexing start almost immediately.

For async indexes (like lucene), the changes to repository or index are picked up in next run of AsyncIndexUpdate job.

Reindex flag will recreate the index from scratch therefore it is a recommended flag to use when you modify an existing index. A new index is always created from scratch because there is no previous checkpoint (*before* point) for that index and everything in the repository matching the criteria will be indexed afresh.

More information can be found in the official [docs](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/query/indexing.html) specifically under the [reindex section](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/query/indexing.html#reindexing).

> New indexes are built automatically once the index definition is stored.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a work-around: Setup your index defs the way you want except that keep `type=disabled`. Let it hold for a few seconds (basically, let at least one async indexing cycle finish). Then set `type=<your-index-type>`. Btw, post oak 1.6, you'd also need to set `refresh=true` to convince oak that you want this change (change in `type`) to be stored internally.